# How do I color more a button, with different colors in tkinter ttk.button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors

I want to color the buttons, but at the moment I only found to color all at once.

I tried by `bg = "red"` inside the `ttk.button()`, but it returned me error the following error:

> / _ tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton",foreground="red")

#Botoes para funcoes da treeview
ttk.Button (text='Deletar', command = self.delete).grid(row=5,column=0, sticky = W + E)
ttk.Button (text='Editar', command = self.editar).grid(row=5,column=1, sticky = W + E)
```

I hope you can help me, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use *bg* or *fg* short forms of *background* and *foreground* in `ttk.Style()` you've to use complete words *background* and *foreground* to configure a style.

> tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"

The error you're getting is because you can't pass **-bg** as a argument to `ttk.Button()`. To configure the style of any ttk widget you have to use `ttk.Style` with their respected style names like for *Button : "TButton", Label : "TLabel", Frame : "TFrame"* and so on see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) of Tk themed widgets.

To make separate styles for different buttons then you can create custom style names.

For example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

button1_style = ttk.Style() # style for button1
# Configure the style of the button here (foreground, background, font, ..)
button1_style.configure('B1.TButton', foreground='red', background='blue')
button1 = ttk.Button(text='Deletar', style='B1.TButton')
button1.pack()

button2_style = ttk.Style() # style for button2
# Configure the style of the button here (foreground, background, font, ..)
button2_style.configure('B2.TButton', foreground='blue', background='red')
button2 = ttk.Button(text='Editar', style='B2.TButton')
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```